# How to reduce data loading time in fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, progressdialog

I am having an activity in my android application which has several fragments as tabs. Each tab has independent API calls. I am using Progress Dialog to show and dismiss the data loading UI. This activity takes lot of time to dismiss the Progress Dialog. I hope it dismiss only after loading all details from all fragments. Is it possible to make independent for each fragment so that I can reduce the loading time?

//Activity

```
     @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        getDatePicker();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_homescreen);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        toggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.sideNavView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

      }

public void getDatePicker() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeScreenActivity.this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    View dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_picker_dialog, null);
    datePicker = dialog.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
    final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd");

    builder.setView(dialog)
            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Some calculation about date...

                  titleArray.clear();

                  for (int i = 0; i <= elapsed; i++) {
...
                    titleArray.add(...);
                  }

                  HomeScreenPagerAdapter homeScreenPagerAdapter = new HomeScreenPagerAdapter(HomeScreenActivity.this, getSupportFragmentManager(), titleArray);
                  ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
                  viewPager.setAdapter(homeScreenPagerAdapter);
                  TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                  tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                  tabs.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            })
            });
    builder.create();
    builder.show();
  }
```

And the following is the Pager Adapter

```
public class HomeScreenPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

  @StringRes
  private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.home_tab1, R.string.home_tab2, R.string.home_tab3};
  private final Context mContext;

  private static List<String> titleArray;

  public HomeScreenPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, List<String> titleArray) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
    this.titleArray = titleArray;
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
      HomeScreenFragment homeScreenFragment = new HomeScreenFragment();
      return homeScreenFragment;
    } else if (position > 0) {
      HomeScreenFixturesOneFragment homeScreenFragment1 = new HomeScreenFixturesOneFragment();
      return homeScreenFragment1;
    }
    HomeScreenFragment homeScreenFragment = new HomeScreenFragment();
    return homeScreenFragment;
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titleArray.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return titleArray.size();
  }
}
```

And I have a fragment to load on the tabs

Comment: Yes.  Its also possible to load the first fragment, get rid of the dialog, then optimistically load the other tabs data in the background.  How to do it in your case we have no idea, as you provided no code.

Comment: I have edit my question. Please help